# Duplicate records created while joining on two different columns names in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes, df1, df2,  where I would like to join on two different table names. However, I am getting a final output with an exponentially increased records number.

**Data**

df1

```
site planq tr   unit    alias   energy
ny   q1 22      du1     du_cc   10
ny   q1 22      du1     du_cc   10
ny   q1 22      du1     du_cc   10
dc   q2 22      aa1     aa_cc   8
dc   q2 22      aa1     aa_cc   8
dc   q2 22      aa1     aa_cc   8
dc   q2 22      aa1     aa_cc   8
```

df2

```
serial  sku type    reason  id
34444   d1  d       ok      ny
34444   d1  d       ok      ny
34444   d1  d       ok      ny
555     a1  a       np      dc
555     a1  a       np      dc
```

**Desired**

```
site    planqtr unit    alias   energy  serial  sku type    reason  id
ny      q1 22   du1     du_cc   10      34444   d1  d       ok      ny
ny      q1 22   du1     du_cc   10      34444   d1  d       ok      ny
ny      q1 22   du1     du_cc   10      34444   d1  d       ok      ny
dc      q2 22   aa1     aa_cc   8       555     a1  a       np      dc
dc      q2 22   aa1     aa_cc   8       555     a1  a       np      dc
dc      q2 22   aa1     aa_cc   8       NaN     NaN NaN     NaN     NaN
dc      q2 22   aa1     aa_cc   8       NaN     NaN NaN     NaN     NaN
```

**Doing**

```
join = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left',left_on= ['id'], right_on = ['site'])
```

However, I am getting a final output with an exponentially increased records number. I am unsure why the output is showing thousands of rows of outputs. Any suggestions or advice is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Update:

I think you are not clear on the requirement. I saw the records carefully, and there's no way a join would give you the required output.

Though, I can help you get the required output using concat. But I am not sure if that would serve your main purpose. Here's the code, anyways:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    site planq  tr  unit    alias   energy  serial  sku type    reason  id
0   ny  q1  22  du1 du_cc   10  34444   d1  d   ok  ny
1   ny  q1  22  du1 du_cc   10  34444   d1  d   ok  ny
2   ny  q1  22  du1 du_cc   10  34444   d1  d   ok  ny
3   dc  q2  22  aa1 aa_cc   8   555     a1  a   np  dc
4   dc  q2  22  aa1 aa_cc   8   555     a1  a   np  dc
5   dc  q2  22  aa1 aa_cc   8   NaN    NaN  NaN NaN NaN
6   dc  q2  22  aa1 aa_cc   8   NaN    NaN  NaN NaN NaN
```

PS: Ignore the spacing of the headers.

#### Old answer:

You need to do

```
join = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left',left_on= ['site'], right_on = ['id'])
```

The `left_on` argument corresponds to the data that is on the left hand side and vice versa.

#### Explanation:

The difference between the two is that `concat` simply puts the two dataframes side by side (if passed `axis=1`, whereas it puts them on top-down if `axis=0` is passed) whereas `merge` is totally different.

Merge is like a cartesian product. It will connect two rows of a dataframe only if there's a connecting point between them (based on the `on`s (`left-on`, `right-on`)) that you provide. Now what would happen if there are multiple such connecting points??? The output "would explode". For eg. in your case, there are multiple "ny"s in the site columns and in the "id" column. If you join, what it actually does is connect every "ny" to every other possible "ny" giving you a total of 3x3 = 9 rows. See in the merge output below:

Merge output:

```
    site    planq   tr  unit    alias   energy  serial  sku type    reason  id
0   ny  q1  22  du1 du_cc   10  34444   d1  d   ok  ny
1   ny  q1  22  du1 du_cc   10  34444   d1  d   ok  ny
2   ny  q1  22  du1 du_cc   10  34444   d1  d   ok  ny
3   ny  q1  22  du1 du_cc   10  34444   d1  d   ok  ny
4   ny  q1  22  du1 du_cc   10  34444   d1  d   ok  ny
5   ny  q1  22  du1 du_cc   10  34444   d1  d   ok  ny
6   ny  q1  22  du1 du_cc   10  34444   d1  d   ok  ny
7   ny  q1  22  du1 du_cc   10  34444   d1  d   ok  ny
8   ny  q1  22  du1 du_cc   10  34444   d1  d   ok  ny
9   dc  q2  22  aa1 aa_cc   8   555 a1  a   np  dc
10  dc  q2  22  aa1 aa_cc   8   555 a1  a   np  dc
11  dc  q2  22  aa1 aa_cc   8   555 a1  a   np  dc
12  dc  q2  22  aa1 aa_cc   8   555 a1  a   np  dc
13  dc  q2  22  aa1 aa_cc   8   555 a1  a   np  dc
14  dc  q2  22  aa1 aa_cc   8   555 a1  a   np  dc
15  dc  q2  22  aa1 aa_cc   8   555 a1  a   np  dc
16  dc  q2  22  aa1 aa_cc   8   555 a1  a   np  dc
```

Similarly, you can see for the rows being `merge`d on "dc", there are a total of 4x2 = 8 resultant rows. Thus making it a total of 17 rows, and thus the "explosion"xD.

Answer (score 1):

You happen to have a minor typo on how you join the table. Try the following code with correct join indexes.

```py
res = df1.merge(df2,how='left',right_on=['id'], left_on=['site'])
```